# converting pandas dataframe into dictionary??

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

I have a pandas dataframe as `news_dataset`where column `id` is an article ID and column `Content` is Article content (large text). Given as,

```
ID      Content
17283   WASHINGTON — Congressional Republicans have...
17284   After the bullet shells get counted, the blood...
17285   When Walt Disney’s “Bambi” opened in 1942, cri...
17286   Death may be the great equalizer, but it isn’t...
17287   SEOUL, South Korea — North Korea’s leader, ...
```

Now, all I want to convert pandas dataframe into dictionary such as `ID` would be a key and `Content` will the value. Basically, what I have done at first something like,

```
dd={}
for i in news_dataset['ID']:
    for j in news_dataset['Content']:
        dd[j]=i
```

This piece of code is pathetic and taking so much time(> 4 minutes) to get processed. So, after checking for some better approaches(stackoverflow). What I have finally did is,

```
id_array=[]
content_array=[]
for id_num in news_dataset['ID']:
    id_array.append(id_num)
for content in news_dataset['Content']:
    content_array.append(content)
news_dict=dict(zip(id_array,content_array))
```

This code takes nearly 15 seconds to get executed.

What I want to ask is,

i) what's wrong in first code and why it take so much time to get processed?

ii) Does using `for` loop inside another `for` loop is wrong way to do iterations when it comes to large text data?

iii) what would be right way to create dictionary using `for` loop within single piece of query?

Answer (score 3):

I think generally loops in pandas should be avoid if exist some non loop, obviously vectorized alternatives.

You can create `index` by column `ID` and call [`Series.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_dict.html):

```
news_dict=news_dataset.set_index('ID')['Content'].to_dict()
```

Or `zip`:

```
news_dict=dict(zip(news_dataset['ID'],news_dataset['Content']))
#alternative
#news_dict=dict(zip(news_dataset['ID'].values, news_dataset['Content'].values))
```

**Performance**:

```
np.random.seed(1425)

#1000rows sample
news_dataset = pd.DataFrame({'ID':np.arange(1000),
                             'Content':np.random.choice(list('abcdef'), size=1000)})

#print (news_dataset)
```

---

```
In [98]: %%timeit
    ...: dd={}
    ...: for i in news_dataset['ID']:
    ...:     for j in news_dataset['Content']:
    ...:         dd[j]=i
    ...: 
61.7 ms ± 2.39 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)


In [99]: %%timeit
    ...: id_array=[]
    ...: content_array=[]
    ...: for id_num in news_dataset['ID']:
    ...:     id_array.append(id_num)
    ...: for content in news_dataset['Content']:
    ...:     content_array.append(content)
    ...: news_dict=dict(zip(id_array,content_array))
    ...: 
251 µs ± 3.14 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [100]: %%timeit
     ...: news_dict=news_dataset.set_index('ID')['Content'].to_dict()
     ...: 
584 µs ± 9.69 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [101]: %%timeit
     ...: news_dict=dict(zip(news_dataset['ID'],news_dataset['Content']))
     ...: 
106 µs ± 3.94 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [102]: %%timeit
     ...: news_dict=dict(zip(news_dataset['ID'].values, news_dataset['Content'].values))
     ...: 
122 µs ± 891 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```